# php producing file tree

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I found jquery can generate file tree structure based on existing folders and files in web server:-

1. http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#demo
2. http://www.mekya.com/blog/lang/eng/2010/03/demo-of-editable-jquery-tree-with-php-codes-duzenlenebilir-jquery-agac-yapisinin-demosu/

Actually, they are too advanced. I just need to create some folder making and file uploading functions, and mark their relativity in database, and present them in file tree like diagram. Is there any suitable option for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of those have a pretty strong set of options. Have you tried toying with them? You can probably dumb it down for your purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a small class for representing tree-structures in PHP.

https://github.com/phunkei/php_mysql_tree

Probably you can adapt that for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder using PHP with the mkdir function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

information about uploaded files are found in the $_FILES global...

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PHP function [MKDir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), when you upload a file ask the user to create a new folder or use an existing folder. You can handle the upload process in separate method after you verified the folder has been created or exist.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `RecursiveTreeIterator` to iterate over the files and present them in an ascii tree.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivetreeiterator.php